# Mesh not following linked bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

So the fingers of my mesh do not seem to work properly. I have checked my weights over and over and it doesnt appear than any of the faces are unapplied to the fingers or hands. This is my first rig though so I might just be doing something wrong. The fingers work fine when operating them alone but when the whole arm moves portions of the fingers do not come with the hand and they elongate, then the finger bones still operate the fingers just at the wrong location.

Images to show what I mean-

[image]

Here are the weights applied to the front finger and the hand, nothings isnt weighted.

Hand

[image]

Finger

[image]

The mesh itself is kind of clunky with everything but i assume its due to my attempt at making the arms able to bend crazily.

Comment: Didi you make the weights in edit mode, or in weight paint mode?

Comment: I made the weights in edit mode. Sorry for such a long reply. Been busy with the start of the semester.

Comment: Ok so what's happening is that every vertex you selected has 100% weight on that particular bone. Try using weight paint mode and see how that works out. if it doesn't, upload your file via [this](http://www.pasteall.org/) site.

Comment: You may need to un-parent the armature, then re-parent with automatic weights.